# Generate *.app file with only Command Line Tools and Terminal(without Xcode)

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode9, xcode9.2

I have searched a bit about this but didn't find anything useful. The file bundle *.app is generate by Xcode after I run the project with the 'Debug' or 'Release' mode in the scheme configuration in the following paths:

```
/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app
/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp/Build/Products/Release/MyApp.app
```

Does anyone know with only the Command Line Tools and the terminal (without having to install 5 GB of Xcode) if there is a way(after i cloned a repo of a macOS App) to generate the *.app file of the program thus i can avoid to upload it directly to the repository ?

Comment: did you find an answer to this?